# Only embed unique elements with mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I use `$addToSet` because I don't want any duplicates.

```
children = children.map(child => new ChildModel({
  a: child.a,
  b: child.b
}));

ParentModel.findByIdAndUpdate(parentModelId, {
  $addToSet: {
    children: {
      $each: children
    }
  }
}, (err, doc) => {
  // ...
});
```

But if I use the code above, the code snippet `new ChildModel()` will cause it to assign an automatically created id to each element, so all the elements will, naturally, be unique.

How can I make sure that I don't add multiple elements to the field `children` with the same values `a` and `b`?

## Edit

Model Schemas

```
const childrenModelSchema = new Schema({
  a: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  b: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  c: [String]
});

const parentModelSchema = new Schema({
  children: [childrenModelSchema]
});
```

Comment: Can you show the schema definitions for both models?

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Try creating a unique compound index on the `childrenModelSchema` as `childrenModelSchema.index({a: 1, b: 1}, {unique: true});`

Comment: Instead of creating array of `ChildModel` elements, just create an array of the `Child` schema object (no model, no id). the `$addToSet` will automatically add `_id` for each element

Comment: so it should be `children = children.map(child => new childModelSchema({` instead of `children = children.map(child => new ChildModel({`?

Comment: The unique index has no effect :S